# Webapi unable to write to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i created a simple webapi and a simple webpage with different ports to register a new user. when my webpage consume the webapi. it always show
This database was create. and it works fine with local host from the same webapi project.
i already added my IIS application pool to the mysql security already.

**Error 500**

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'atestDB'

i noticed that if i remove this line in the connection string. it will works fine.

```
Integrated Security=True
```

so my question is. can i go without integrated in my sql connection string?

**web page**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#btnregister').click(function ()
        {

            RegisterBindingModel.Email = $('#Email').val();
            RegisterBindingModel.Password = $('#Password').val();
            RegisterBindingModel.ConfirmPassword = $('#ConfirmPassword').val();
            debugger
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.azapi.com:81/api/account/register',
                type:'Post',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(RegisterBindingModel),
                success: function(data) {
                    debugger
                    alert(data)
                },
                error: function (err) {

                    alert(err.status)
                }

            })

        })

    }
    )
</script>
```

**webapi**

using standard registeration api from .net
with cros enabled.

```
 EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: When you created your database, did you create a login for that database that has admin privledges?  If not, do so and replace `Integrated Security=True` with your username and password that you created for admin privledges to that database

Comment: Your connection string should look something like this: `<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ConnectionStringName.csdl|res://*/Models.ConnectionStringName.ssdl|res://*/Models.ConnectionStringName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=serverName;initial catalog=databaseName;user id=userId;password=password123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: yes i have admin account for database. sa. the code works find if i port the registration page to webapi project. i will not get this error when using localhost

Comment: this is my connection string`  `  `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-4JA6G4O;Initial Catalog=atestDB;User ID=sa;Password=123;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: i am just doing a normal insert from registration api only

Comment: If you use a Username and password.. then don't include `Integrated Security`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set *Integrated Security* to *false*. If you set it to false the ID and password in the connection are used to athenticate you. If you do so keep in mind that it's not a good idea (actually it's a very bad idea) to have sensitiv data, like passwords, hard coded. There are a few ways to avoid this. If you like to see two ways check out the answer to  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029701/what-is-the-best-place-to-inject-the-db-password-to-the-default-ef-connection-st).

Comment: When you use EF and create your connection string, you're asked if you would like to include sensitive data in the connection string.  The OP could just click "Don't include sensitive information"

Comment: Yes your're right. I've updated my answer and linked a post which explains how to provide the data if it's not included.

Comment: whole project was default.i didnt not create anything yet.The database was created when i create new record

Comment: As i said. You can set Integrated Security to false. Instead of using the windows athentification it will use the ID  and password in your connection string.

Comment: any draw back on setting to false?

Comment: If you're working with a team the only problem is that every developer knows the password and username for the db. Otherwise nothing comes into my mind at the moment.