# How to encrypt Connection Strings credentials in Web.Config file in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

I'm working on asp.net project I have to encrypt credential in web.config file

```
<add name="ConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=sqlexpress;
                       Initial Catalog=Employee;
                       User ID=testUser;
                       Password=testPassword"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypting Connection String in web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706613/encrypting-connection-string-in-web-config)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aspnet_regiis` to do this.

As an example:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

[**Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: @BuddhikaSamith no probs. 

Comment: what happen when some one used this command. Any suggestions?
`aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"`