# How to add connection string to once for whole solution to use?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Recently I am working on an .Net project. We used EF to handle SQL, when we make an installer of the program, we realize that `app.config` is visible which mean that the connection string is not safe.

I am looking for a way to add connection string (or maybe secret code and username) to the EF so that the connection string is not visible.

Something like change old code from this

```
Using db As ConnectDb.adoSentoEntities= New ConnectDb.adoSentoEntities
                'TODO
End Using
```

to this

```
Using db As ConnectDb.adoSentoEntities= New ConnectDb.adoSentoEntities(ConnectionString)
                'TODO
End Using
```

But since we used connect code to SQL all over the place, changing every single line of code is not possible. There is a way I only need to add connection string once?

Comment: ConnectionStrings section could be encrypted

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#encrypting-configuration-file-sections-using-protected-configuration

Answer (score 1):

You’d be better off encrypting the connection string section in the app.config. You wouldn’t need to make any changes.
Storing any sort of configuration in an assembly can be read using a hex editor.
It’s been answered on here before.
[Encrypting Connection String in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706613/encrypting-connection-string-in-web-config)

You’d be better off using a trusted connection if you’re using SQL Server. The user running the app would need to have permissions and no username and password is required.

Comment: Thank you very much i checked the first link of the marked answer, i am well aware of the encrypting method but the tricky part is how do i let EF get my decrypted connection string instead of the encrypted string?

Comment: I mean it seem to me that that solution will put decrypted connection string back to app.config

Comment: When I used it (with a VB6 dll calling a .net assembly’s the configuration manager knew it was encrypted and did the decryption for me. I’d expect EF to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Save connection string is settings of project properties.

1. Go in project properties.
2. Select settings.
3. Add new setting as connection string and save connection string.
   Then you can use it for whole project.

Comment: Thank, now i only need a way to do it programmatically. i will check if it work, and i will mark your answer as the solution of this question

Comment: I believe that ends up in the app.config